# Running React Apollo website on Android device - the step with react-native is unclear

Tags: android, reactjs, apollo, react-apollo

I'm using that [**React Apollo boilerplate**](https://github.com/howtographql/react-apollo). Now I want to deploy that Website to my Android device. So I did it exactly like the [Running On Device tutorial](https://reactnative.dev/docs/running-on-device) said:

1. **Enable Debugging over USB**

   - all fine
2. **Plug in your device via USB**

   - `adb devices`
   - my list looks like this:

```
       List of devices attached
       5141a720        device
```

So this looks good.

3. **Run your app**

   - but here I have an issue because I have no idea what `react-native` means
   - `npx react-native run-android`
   - results in `react-native is not known`

Could it be that my project is not a `react-native` project and that's why react-native is not a proper solution for my case?

How to run that website on my Android device without transforming it as APK file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just added those two lines and `npm/yarn install`:

```
"react-native": "^0.62.2",
"react-native-cli": "^2.0.1",
```

and tried again `npx react-native run-android` and now it seemed to work. But a got a message that said:

> error Android project not found. Are you sure this is a React Native
>   project? If your Android files are located in a non-standard location
>   (e.g. not inside 'android' folder), consider setting
>   `project.android.sourceDir` option to point to a new location. Run CLI
>   with --verbose flag for more details.

So obviously that `android` folder is missing. Here it helped to run `npx react-native init "test"`. That created a subfolder called test. Here I simply movedthat android folder to my project.

And now `npx react-native run-android` works.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a React Native expert, but from what I do understand about the tool, you would need to have created special components for rendering on native devices (fc).

A tool that might suite your needs better would be capacitor:
Installation: https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/getting-started
Workflow: https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/basics/workflow

A quick summary of the workflow:

1. Build the react-app `npm run build`
2. Create a capacitor.config.json:

```
{
    "appId": "com.example.app",
    "appName": "Example",
    "bundledWebRuntime": false,
    "npmClient": "npm",
    "webDir": "build",
    "cordova": {},
    "linuxAndroidStudioPath": "/mnt/s/android-studio/bin/studio.sh"
}
```

3. Open the android emulator: `npx cap open android`

Hope this helps.

Comment: That looks good, but I'm using yarn. Can I do the same with yarn as well? And it is not possible to pass through the localhost:3000 to my device? I mean a solution could be creating a ngrok session, that proxies my localcost to the web. But simply passing through the website would be the best for now. I will give yours a try, hopefully I'm able to run it.

Comment: If you have yarn, you should also have npm. So I believe that yarn run build and npx will work

Comment: Thanks again for your idea. I just tried it again and now it somehow works. I don't know if was missing really missing the deps but at least now working. But good idea anyway with Capacitor. Maybe coming back to it if React-native does not do what I need.